# can not print the return value from a function

Tags: python, syntax, for-loop, indentation

I was trying to do simple function in Python, and this function should return a value.
The problem is, when I tried to print the output of the function, no value appears.

Please find below the Python code:

```
# Fibonacci Series.
def Fibonacci(num) :
F_1 = 0
F_2 = 1
Fibo = 0
for i in list(range(num)) :
    Fibo = F_1 + F_2
    F_1 = F_2
    F_2 = Fibo
    return Fibo

print(Fibonacci(7))
```

Comment: What output/error do you get? Literally nothing?

Comment: Yes literally nothing.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but it's worth noting you can only ever return one value from a function - you probably want `yield` to make a generator (and then wrap the function call in `list()` or print in a loop to get all the values).

Comment: i knew my problem , i would delete this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue with your code formatting,

Format it like this and it works, I just tested

```
# Fibonacci Series.
def Fibonacci(num) :
    F_1 = 0
    F_2 = 1
    Fibo = 0
    for i in list(range(num)) :
        Fibo = F_1 + F_2
        F_1 = F_2
        F_2 = Fibo
    return Fibo

print(Fibonacci(7))
```

Python is dependant upon the tabbed indentation for execution blocks in the same way C++ or Java is on curly braces { }

Comment: If that was the issue, OP would have received a Syntax Error.

Comment: The reason it returns 1 is if return is tabbed into the for loop so it returns immediately, giving 1

Answer (score 1):

Just that your indentation was wrong . Python is heavily dependent on Tabs and spaces. This works

```
# Fibonacci Series.
def Fibonacci(num) :
  F_1 = 0
  F_2 = 1
  Fibo = 0
  for i in list(range(num)) :
      Fibo = F_1 + F_2
      F_1 = F_2
      F_2 = Fibo
  return Fibo

print(Fibonacci(7))
```